# Java calculate week number with February first week as no.1 week?

Tags: java, calendar, week-number, java.util.date

I am trying to calculate week numbers where the start of the week number must start with February first week. For example. Feb 2-feb 8 2015 the week number must be 1. Please help me as I am new to this environment and I am able to calculate the week numbers starting with January first week.

To add more context I am trying to implement a Broadcast calendar in java with week 1 starting from February.

Comment: if you could try to be a bit more clear what you're looking for, that would be helpful. I don't understand your example. So would the 9-15 be week 2, etc. etc.? and why do you say must start with February first week, then switch to January? Which is it?

Comment: Yea 9-15 must be second week . I am using Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR to find out the week number currently

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Specify your desired date as an anchor date, a date from which we count weeks. You want ordinal week numbers, so add one to avoid a week numbered zero.

The [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) offers the [`between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method to calculate elapsed time.

```
LocalDate anchor = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.FEBRUARY , 2 );

LocalDate feb5 = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.FEBRUARY , 5 );
LocalDate feb8 = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.FEBRUARY , 8 );
LocalDate feb9 = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.FEBRUARY , 9 );

System.out.println( feb5 + " is in week # " + ( ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( anchor , feb5 ) + 1 ) );
System.out.println( feb8 + " is in week # " + ( ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( anchor , feb8 ) + 1 ) );
System.out.println( feb9 + " is in week # " + ( ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( anchor , feb9 ) + 1 ) );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/zbXhqW).

> 2015-02-05 is in week # 1
>
> 2015-02-08 is in week # 1
>
> 2015-02-09 is in week # 2

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

So just use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
c.setTime( sdf.parse("2/2/2015"));
out.println( c.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR ));
```

to get the week number for February 2, and offset it by the number of weeks between Jan. 1st. So

```
c.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR )) - 4;
```

or however many weeks are in front of it.